# Zenoss - install.sh doesnt ask for mysql password

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, zenoss

i'm trying to install zenoss on a ubuntu-14.04 virtual machine. I followed the following guide "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Zenoss". After some errors with dependencies, I have the following error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

In many posts and guides they say that i will be asked for the mysql root password, but i didnt :/

Perhaps any of you had the same problem or have a tipp or soultuion for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: Also, the 14th step in the guide you refer describes how to set a password for the `root` account of the database.

Comment: Version is Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu), i have set an password for the mysql server but the zenoss script doesnt ask during install

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not asking for the password, but to complete the install you could drop a `.my.cnf` into the installing user's home directory containing

```
[client]
user = root
password = MySecurePassword
```

Of course you'll need to figure out how to tell zenoss the password once it's installed, but at least this will get you a bit further.  Don't forget to make the file's permissions secure and remove it afterwards.